# no carga boostrap

Tags: html5, css3

estoy empezando con boostrap, alquien sabe que esta mal en mi código? parece que no me carga bootstrap, no usa ni las fuentes, ni la tipología ni nada de las librerías. Las rutas de las carpetas están bien. he revisado todo y no entiendo porque no cambia el formato, se ve igual que si no hiciera referencia a las librerias, siento que es algo muy basico pero es lo que tiene ser autodidacta, jejeje. un saludo a todos y gracias.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>mi pagina</title>
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <header class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="index.html" title="Chaplin Cafe">
                <img src="imagenes/logo_chaplin.jpg" alt="logo Chaplin Cafe"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <nav style="margin-top:50px">
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ChaplinCafeTorredelmar/" title="Establecimiento">Establecimiento</a>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/ChaplinCafeTorredelmar/about/?ref=page_internal" title="Contacto">Conctacto</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="slogan" class="container text-center bg-info">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        <h2>Un Lugar Magico Donde Todo Puede Pasar</h2>
    </div>
    <footer class="container-fluid">
        &copy; Chaplin Cafe, Since 1984.
    </footer>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
</body>
```

tenia la carpeta del proyecto en una carpeta con mas proyectos y las carpetas de bootstrap en la raíz del proyecto en cuestión, no se porque pero se arreglo aislando la carpeta fuera de la de proyectos. Lo extraño es que no funcionara tampoco con el enlace al CDN como sugirió el compañero. La razón de que lo pusiera en local es porque estoy aprendiendo y así es como lo dictaba el cursillo, pero gracias a vosotros he aprendido otra manera de hacerlo. Gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda

Comment: Este enlace es correcto `href="css/bootstrap.min.css"` ?, es decir tienes a bootstrap dentro de una capeta llamada css?, recomiendo **abre la consola del navegador y revisa si te devuelve algún error**

Comment: Podrías abrir la consola del navegador y verificar el error que marca?

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres usar bootstrap en local, cuando puedes usar la versión que ellos ofrecen en su CDN? Prueba a cambiarlo por esto: `<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">` Así vas menos cargado, porque se incluirá el archivo de forma segura desde el CDN de bootstrap.

Comment: ... y también para la parte Javascript que tienes en el footer: `<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: Para que funcione tal como tienes las rutas, tu archivo `html` debe estar almacenado en la raíz de la carpeta donde tienes las carpetas `css` y `js`

Comment: Muéstrame por favor la estructura de carpetas de tu proyecto para poder si donde están los archivos y saber si los estas referenciando de forma correcta

Answer (score 0):

intenta importar el css de boostrap con esta etiqueta:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: sigue sin funcionar, no se que estoy haciedo mal, el codigo parece correcto

Answer (score 0):

Agrega las referencias de **CDN** que ofrece **`Boostrap`** revisa este snippet

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>mi pagina</title>
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="index.html" title="Chaplin Cafe">
                <img src="imagenes/logo_chaplin.jpg" alt="logo Chaplin Cafe"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <nav style="margin-top:50px">
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ChaplinCafeTorredelmar/" title="Establecimiento">Establecimiento</a>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/ChaplinCafeTorredelmar/about/?ref=page_internal" title="Contacto">Conctacto</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="slogan" class="container text-center bg-info">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        <h2>Un Lugar Magico Donde Todo Puede Pasar</h2>
    </div>
    <footer class="container-fluid">
        &copy; Chaplin Cafe, Since 1984.
    </footer>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Segun tu codigo debiste descargar el codigo de bootstrap, en su defecto traerlo directo desde un sito web. en vez de

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

coloca este

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 0):

acabo de notar algo curioso mientras veía este error, espero sirva a los demás, lo que hice fue direccionar desde la carpeta de proyecto, quedando así:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/proyecto/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/proyecto/css/bootstrap.min.css">`